# Delete Row with Input Button

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table that will allow me to delete a row by clicking a delete button. I did find an article on here at the following link that did provide some help but I am still unable to get it to work: [Show all rows in mysql table then give option to delete specific ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302554/show-all-rows-in-mysql-table-then-give-option-to-delete-specific-ones) .I have written most of the code but I am having problem with line 10 on the delete.php page. Ideas?

**Main.php**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cs_general_info");

echo "<table><tr><td>Delete</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Address</td>td>Phone</td><td>E-Mail Address</td></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

<tr>
<td>
<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Delete"></form>
</td>

<?php

  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

**Delete.php**

```
"DELETE FROM cs_general_info WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($delete_id);
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated. Use `PDO` or at least bind your parameters.

Comment: No security at all?? I can see few ways how to break this code easily...

Comment: What is the problem you have with line 10?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully `delete.php` is more than that single line. In `delete.php` you will want to catch the `POST` method and the `$row[id]`; bind it, then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the id of the row you want to delete in your `delete.php` file, you need to get the variable, like this:

```
$delete_id = $_POST['delete'];
```

WARNING:  This is the very basic functionality you need to get this to work.  However, you will need to implement many other levels of security before this should ever go into any production code.

Comment: I am fairly new to PHP and everyone keeps mentioning security. Do you have an references I can refer to to learn more about PHP security?

Comment: Google "PHP SQL injection" or something similar.  There are millions of articles out there.  To get you started, here is an article on the PHP.net site that at least gives you a basic overview of the issues we are talking about: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

If that is your `delete.php`, then you are missing a lot. You need a database connection and you need to execute the `SQL` command against the database. But that is the least of your worries until you get your parameters via `$_POST`.

[Here is the `PDO` Manual for the database connection and `SQL` execution.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[And here is the manual for `$_POST`.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 0):

You want to either put a link or inline form within each of your table’s rows, and then have a script that deletes the specified row and returns the user to your page.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $result->title; ?></td>
      <td>
        <form action="delete.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $result->id; ?>" />
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then **delete.php**:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['id']) && intval($_POST['id']) > 0) {
    // create PDO instance; assign it to $db variable
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1";
    $smt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $smt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $smt->execute();
}

header('Location: index.php');
```